# Имя существительное

Tags: существительные

Имя существительное — это часть речи, обозначающая предмет (субстанцию) и выражающая это значение в словоизменительных категориях числа и падежа и в несловоизменительной категории рода.
Существительные разделяются на несколько лексико-грамматических разрядов.

Какое существительное имеет не такие категории словоизменения, как остальные?

1. джунгли
2. ходули
3. родители
4. жмурки
5. консервы

Я прекрасно понимаю, что они будут отличаться по числам ( одни только во множественном, а другие и в том и другом), но задача выбрать ОДНО слово. Во всех просмотренных мною словарях и интернете сказано, что Джунгли, Жмурки, Консервы - только множественное, а вот Родители и Ходули - и то, и другое

Comment: Просклоняйте эти существительные и сами все увидите. Домашние задания здесь не выполняют.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю, что они будут отличаться по числам ( одни только во множественном, а другие и в том и другом), но задача выбрать ОДНО слово. Во всех просмотренных мною словарях и интернете сказано, что Джунгли, Жмурки, Консервы - только множественное, а вот Родители и Ходули - и то, и другое.

Comment: Откуда этот вопрос? Анастасия, вам следовала бы в тексте вопроса обрисовать возникшие трудности при решении. Тогда бы и разговоров про домашниее задание не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Джунгли – джунгля. Ходули – ходуля. Родители – родитель. Жмурки – жмурка. Консервы – консерва.

(Не подсказка, а наводка на мысль).

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю, что они будут отличаться по числам ( одни только во множественном, а другие и в том и другом), но задача выбрать ОДНО слово. Во всех просмотренных мною словарях и интернете сказано, что Джунгли, Жмурки, Консервы - только множественное, а вот Родители и Ходули - и то, и другое.

Comment: Вам же дали наводку. Посмотрите внимательно!

Comment: Благодарю! Только сейчас поняла. Спасибо, что помогли, а то бы я так и седела зациклившись на числе.

Comment: Анастасия9А, интересно, и какое же слово Вы в конечном итоге  выбрали? И в чём его отличие от других приведённых в задании слов?

Comment: Да, действительно. Напишите, пожалуйста, чтобы мы поняли, правильно ли Вы выбрали ил нет.

Comment: Ха. Я-то считал, что "ходули" есть только во мн.ч. Может, и составители задания так считали? Но в словарях "ходуля" имеется.

Comment: А Анастасия9А, увы, молчит...